# Dystopian novel with heterochromia, bathroom symbols

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

So basically I read a book a while back like 7 or more years ago and it was so good I want to own it but I can’t recall almost any specific details about the title or author. It’s about this rebellious girl with one blue eye and one brown eye.  She’s trapped in some all girls prison or camp that she can’t get out of. At the end of the book she ends up dying at the hands of the villain, who takes his sunglasses off to reveal he also had one or and brown eye, meaning he was her father. I do remember the book cover vividly, it had a bunch of women bathroom symbols all lined up in grey, and one of them stood out bright orange. Please help it was an all-time favorite.

Answer (score 13):

### [*Fearless*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0763636371)

This is *Fearless*, by Tim Lott.

Of course, from the Amazon description, we can see that it is dystopian:

> In the not-too-distant future, the world is safe from terrorists, the
> streets are clean, and girls labeled “juvies” or “mindcrips” have been
> hidden away behind the smartly painted exterior of the City Community
> Faith School. Their birth names are forgotten and replaced with a
> letter and number, but they give each other nicknames like Tattle or
> Stench or Little Fearless. As they slave away at chores, Little
> Fearless, who is actually the bravest girl in the school, tells the
> other girls stories, stories about the day their families will return
> for them. Little Fearless’s own hope and conviction spur her on a
> dangerous adventure — a bold and unthinkable plan that will either
> save the imprisoned girls or mean the end of Little Fearless herself,
> or both.

[image]

As you can see from the cover, we have the “women bathroom symbols.”

And here’s another cover, showing the blue and brown eyes:

[image]

These are also mentioned in the book…

> Stargazer unlocked the door and pushed it open. She saw a small figure
> lying on a plain wooden bench on the other side of the cage. The
> figure was so thin and pale, it was hard to know if it was Little
> Fearless or not. Her hair had grown back a little bit but was dirty
> and tangled, and she wore an old pair of striped pyjamas that looked
> like they had never been washed. Only when she opened her eyes to
> reveal one brown eye and one blue eye could Stargazer be sure that it
> was her best friend.
>
> <sub>*Fearless*</sub>

…where the villainous Controller does indeed have the same eyes:

> Stargazer stared. In the flickering light she saw for the first time
> his eyes, the eyes he had concealed all the years he had been at the
> Institute. And one was brown. And the other was blue.
>
> <sub>*Fearless*</sub>

Comment: I met a few people (at least two) with eyes like that in Northern Germany. Must be a common mutation there.